# Getting Foreign Address for TCP

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am trying to run a simple java server on a machine connected to a university network. Although when i check netstat the server only got Local Address and the Foreign Address is 0.0.0.0 . Is this because of a firewall ? How could i get around this ? Thanks .

p.s Im using TCP for the connection.

Comment: A local address of "0.0.0.0" for a listening socket means that it is listening on all possible addresses on the local host.

Comment: The foreign address is 0.0.0.0 not the local.

Comment: @jgauffin Was writing an answer while you wrote your comment. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only *connections* have foreign addresses. A socket that's just listening for connections has no foreign address.

Comment: Yes my question is how can i make it have foreign address so that i can connect to that server from other machines in same network.

Comment: You don't make it have a foreign address. When a `ServerSocket `listens, it returns a `Socket`, which is the endpoint used for communication with the remote socket. It is possible to get the remote address from the endpoint. When a client connects to a server, they will use `Socket` off the bat, and it will get a remote address as soon as connection succeeds.

Comment: @latusaki: You connect to it and then that connection will have a foreign address. You can't make it have a foreign address before you connect because before you connect, there isn't anything to have a foreign address. The listening endpoint is local until something foreign connects to it.

Comment: Ok thanks for that . Any suggestions why the machine 2 can't connect to machine 1 when they are on the same network ? I give to the client the inet address of the server and the port that its running but it cannot connect . Same happens if i try to connect with a telnet. Both machines have firewall by the way.

Comment: @latusaki: Either the firewall is blocking the connection, the machine is not listening, or you are connecting to the wrong IP or port. What error do you get?

Comment: Telnet says could not connect as soon as I start it. If the IP was wrong it would print "trying......" and then fail which is not the case . Also when i type netstat -na i can see the tcp connection with the correct  address and saying LISTENING . So i guess its the firewall

Answer (score 3):

A listening socket must have a *local* address for clients to be able to connect to it. The *local* address is the address of the machine the server program is running on, or "0.0.0.0" if the machine have more than one network address and you want to accept connections on all of them.

When a client connect to your server program you have to `accept` it, and you get a new socket. This new socket will have both a valid *local* and *remote* address. The *local* address is the address of the network interface where it received the connection, while the *remote* address is the address of the client connecting to your server program.

I hope this makes things a little clearer.

Comment: +1 then. You might want to elaborate on "more than one network interfaces" so that the reader doesn't confuse it with more than one NIC.

Comment: Alright I see i misunderstood the meaning of foreign address. Although you got any suggestion on how i can connect to my server from a different machine ? Nether the client or a telnet can connect to my server . To start the server i use the inet address of the running machine and a free port .

Comment: @latusaki The two machines can reach each other I hope? You can check this with e.g. the `ping` command. Other than that I can't say much more without more information. Post another question, possibly with some code for the server, and we will try to help you then.

Comment: The machines should be able to connect since they are on the same network. Although ill test with ping . By the way i am using a GossipRouter ( not sure if you are familiar).

Comment: Did some testing with ping but it doesn't work so far. It does work locally and using the gateway address. If i try to ping another machine i get request timeout . Both machines have same Default Gateway and Subnet Mask (not sure if that matters )